Check if an address is part of a list of subnets
In Ansible, is it possible to test if an IP address is part of a list of subnets?
I.e.: I have a list of subnets, ['10.10.10.0/24','10.10.12.0/24'], and an IP address: 10.10.12.8.
How would I test if the IP address is part of the subnets with a when statement?

The IP manipulations tends to be in the ansible.utils collection, and indeed the first test you can find in this collection is the test in_any_network, which will help you achieve what you are looking for.
Given:
- ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "{{ _ip }} is in {{ _networks }}"
  when: _ip is ansible.utils.in_any_network _networks
  vars:
    _ip: 10.10.12.8
    _networks: ['10.10.10.0/24','10.10.12.0/24']

You will get:
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: 10.10.12.8 is in ['10.10.10.0/24', '10.10.12.0/24']

